# Trouble minimizing a value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, minimize

I'm trying to minimize a value dependant of a function (and therefore optimize the arguments of the function) so the latter matches some experimental data.

Problem is that I don't actually know if I'm coding what I want correctly, or even if I'm using the correct function, because my program gives me an error.

```
import scipy.optimize as op

prac3 = pd.read_excel('Buena.xlsx', sheetname='nl1')

print(prac3.columns)

tmed = 176
te = np.array(prac3['tempo'])
t = te[0:249]
K = np.array(prac3['cond'])
Kexp = K[0:249]
Kinf = 47.8
K0 = 3.02
DK = Kinf - K0
def f(Kinf,DK,k,t):
    return (Kinf-DK*np.exp(-k*t)) 
def err(Kexp,Kcal):
    return ((Kcal-Kexp)**2)

Kcal = np.array(f(Kinf,DK,k,t))
print(Kcal)

dif = np.array(err(Kexp,Kcal))
sumd = sum(dif)
print(sumd)

op.minimize(f, (Kinf,DK,k,t))
```

The error the program gives me reads as it follows:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-fd51b4735eed> in <module>()
     48 print(sumd)
     49 
---> 50 op.minimize(f, (Kinf,DK,k,t))
     51 
     52 

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    352 
    353     """
--> 354     x0 = np.asarray(x0)
    355     if x0.dtype.kind in np.typecodes["AllInteger"]:
    356         x0 = np.asarray(x0, dtype=float)

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    529 
    530     """
--> 531     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    532 
    533 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#3)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error whole message verbatim ( word for word) into your question inlkusding the stacktrace

Comment: You really should paste the whole traceback, not just the error. And ideally give us a stripped-down script that only does the part that's failing, instead of all the other stuff that isn't relevant. Sometimes people will be able to guess the problem anyway, but you shouldn't count on that.

Comment: which variable(s) are you trying to minimize for? And off the top you are using `.optimize` incorrectly. It should be `op.minimize(function, initial guess)`. So only pass `f` and not `(Kinf,DK,k,t)`

Comment: The code I posted is a copypaste of the original, just without the anotations. More precisely, what I'm trying to do here is optimize all the function variables except `t`, to get a minimum value at `sumd`. Again, sorry if this is just too noob, but I'm new in this world, and I still feel a bit lost. And of course, thanks to everybody who is trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that you're passing an array to something that expects a callable. Without seeing your traceback or knowing more of what you're trying to do, I can only guess where this is happening, but my guess is here:

```
op.minimize(f(Kinf,DK,k,t),sumd)
```

From [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), the first parameter is a callable (function). But you're passing whatever `f(Kinf,DK,k,t)` returns as the first argument. And, looking at your `f` function, it looks like it's returning an array, not a function.

My first guess is that you want to minimize `f` over the args `(Kinf, DK, k, t)`? if so, you pass `f` as the function, and the tuple `(Kinf, DK, k, t)` as the args, like this:

```
op.minimize(f, sumd, (Kinf,DK,k,t))
```

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. I've tried your solution, and now it's giving me another error -.-"". I'm editing the original post to match what it is happening now.